# What is a tool to wireframe an app AND then generate HTML + CSS code afterwards

Tags: html, css, wireframing

I love wireframing, since it's mostly faster than coding. After the wireframe process I would like to export HTML + CSS for the different screens, so I only have to add the javascript afterwards to make the app functional. What is a tool that I can use to do this? I just want to have a list of potential candidates, so I know where to look.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! [What's "best" is always subjective](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/157/185): *one man's trash is another man's treasure.* Better describe what would make this software *fitting best for you* – which then enables us to give fitting recommendations. See [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for more hints. Especially missing: what features do you need, what OS must it run on, how much are you willing to spend if it comes to paid software?

Comment: :D thats why i phrased "a tool" not "best tool" in the header, i just want to have a list of tools to look at

Comment: Well, [list questions are no good fit for Q&A sites](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/98366/192154), and hence are [considered off-topic](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/139618/192154). That's why I asked for additional details. We require things to be specific here :) But of course, not being familiar with wireframing, I cannot tell what's missing … Just looks like there is a gap, though I cannot put my finger on it ;)

Comment: What's wrong with a WYSIWYG HTML (and CSS) editor?

Answer (score 2):

Just a few days ago researcher Emil Wallner from France has posted this blogpost:
[Turning Design Mockups Into Code With Deep Learning](https://blog.floydhub.com/turning-design-mockups-into-code-with-deep-learning/). He even posted links to code repos on Github, having names like [Screenshot--to-Code](https://github.com/emilwallner/Screenshot-to-code-in-Keras/) and [pix2code](https://github.com/tonybeltramelli/pix2code).

So you might use this if you are a deep learning expert (I'm not). In their READMEs, these Github repos have links to Showcasing sites.

The blogpost mentions other tools, e.g. Airbnb's [sketch2code](https://airbnb.design/sketching-interfaces/), but I havent'l looked at any of this material.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for all those pointers, but shouldn't that be a comment? This site is about recommending software, not blogs :)